# Is it OK to use the ASP.net SessionId embedded in the HubCallerContext RequestCookies in SignalR 2.x?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I've got a question regarding use of data found within the HubCallerContext.

I notice there's a collection of RequestCookies that hang off of the context.

**They contain the following:**

```
[0]: {[culture, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie]}
[1]: {[__RequestVerificationToken_L0VDSQ2, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie]}
[2]: {[ASP.NET_SessionId, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie]}
[3]: {[XxxAuth, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie]}
```

In our previous implementation of SignalR, we leveraged the SessionId which hung
off of the HttpContext Session. Since use of the Session is no longer supported
in SignalR 2.x, we were forced to look for an alternative.

In doing so, we noticed "ASP.NET_SessionId" in the RequestCookies.
Does anyone know of any issues or restrictions with using it?
Is this a safe option to utilize?

Thoughts?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: Hi John, I'm facing the same issue. I'm also not too enthusiastic about using this workaround, it seems pretty unstable to me. Did you find any other ways to grab the SessionId?

Comment: For now, we've gone with the solution outlined above. That being said, I'm not to excited about having to do it that way. My concern is that somehow SignalR/MVC changes in future releases in such a way that make this solution obsolete. A better solution might have been to use some combination of user authentication/data store to help manage context (replacing reliance on SessionId). The client had performance concerns with that solution, so it was shelved for now.